# Codeigniter trying to connect assets with css file

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

I am working on my first codeigniter project and am trying to put my styling in an assets folder, as it looks like that is best practice. I have tried to set it up the way others have but something is not working! Any help appreciated.

My file structure:

```
application
assets->css->style.css
```

I made a helper application/helpers.utlity_helper.php which contains the following:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 if ( ! function_exists('asset_url()'))
 {
   function asset_url()
   {
      return site_url().'assets/';
   }
 }
```

I set it to autoload:

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form', 'utility');
```

My .htcaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|robots\.txt)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

My routes.php file has:

```
$route['assets/(:any)']='assets/$1';
```

And finally, in my header I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo asset_url();?>css/style.css">
```

But the styles in my style file are not showing up! Please let me know if you see an error or if you know why this is. Thank you!

Comment: `function_exists('asset_url()')` this should be probably this I guess: `function_exists('asset_url')`

Comment: I think your rule `$route['assets/(:any)']='assets/$1';`is wrong.Try without the rule

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I tried changing asset_url() to asset_url and removing the route. Neither change threw any errors, but the css styling is still not showing up!

Comment: The following examples will grant or [deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_core.html#reqall) access to all requests. What if you move that line?

Comment: Your asset_url() function should return `base_url().'assets/';`. What you see `href` value if you view the source of html

Comment: No, asset_url is from the helper I made, so the question is why isn't my use of it working? I did try it with base_url() first and it also did not work

Comment: What is value of `$config['base_url']`?

Comment: @Tpojka it is $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost:8888"

Comment: And is that correct location path of project?

Comment: yes. i am not having trouble accessing any other part of my project.

Comment: Make a test method and just `echo asset_url()` to see what is result.

Comment: it returns http://localhost:8888/index.php/assets/

Comment: Seems like you are losing trailing slash?